# PHP If/Else Multiple Conditionals

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

From what I've read, if statement conditionals should break as soon as a false is found however:

```
if(array_key_exists('cool', $_POST) && $_POST['cool'] == 1)
```

returns an index undefined error. What I *want* to do is check to see if the key is even there and *then* check it's value, but the only way I've been able to do that is:

```
if(array_key_exists('cool', $_POST)) {
  if($_POST['cool'] == 1)
```

and that means I have to have multiple else blacks as well. Is there anyway to do this with less code?

Comment: Use [isset()](http://www.php.net.isset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use isset which is a language construct as opposed to a function call:

```
if(isset($_POST['cool']) && $_POST['cool'] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the key exists in the array:

```
if(array_key_exists('cool',$_POST) && $_POST['cool'] == 1)
```

or use `isset()`.

Comment: isset fixed it. Thank you. I must have been mistyping it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(array_key_exists('cool',$_POST) && $_POST['cool'] == 1)
```